# Matching tuples in Prolog

Tags: prolog, tuples, pattern-matching, operators, associativity

Why does Prolog match `(X, Xs)` with a tuple containing more elements? An example:

```
test2((X, Xs)) :- write(X), nl, test2(Xs).                                    
test2((X)) :- write(X), nl.                                                   
                                                                              
test :-                                                                       
        read(W),                                                               
        test2(W). 

?- test.
|: a, b(c), d(e(f)), g.
a
b(c)
d(e(f))
g
yes
```

Actually this is what I want to achieve but it seems suspicious. Is there any other way to treat a conjunction of terms as a list in Prolog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuple *term* construction with the `,/2` operator is generally right-associative in PROLOG (typically referred to as a *sequence*), so your input of `a, b(c), d(e(f)), g` might well actually be the term `(a, (b(c), (d(e(f)), g)))`. This is evidenced by the fact that your predicate `test2/1`  printed what is shown in your question, where on the first invocation of the first clause of `test2/1`, `X` matched `a` and `Xs` matched `(b(c), (d(e(f)), g))`, then on the second invocation `X` matched `b(c)` and `Xs` matched `(d(e(f)), g)`, and so on.

If you really wanted to deal with a *list* of terms interpreted as a conjunction, you could have used the following:

```
test2([X|Xs]) :- write(X), nl, test2(Xs).                                    
test2([]).
```

...on input `[a, b(c), d(e(f)), g]`. The list structure here is generally interpreted a little differently from tuples constructed with `,/2` (as, at least in SWI-PROLOG, such structures are syntactic sugar for dealing with terms constructed with `./2` in much the same way as you'd construct sequences or tuple terms with `,/2`). This way, you get the benefits of the support of list terms, if you can allow list terms to be *interpreted as conjunctions* in your code. Another alternative is to declare and use your *own* (perhaps infix operator) for conjunction, such as `&/2`, which you could declare as:

```
:- op(500, yfx, &). % conjunction constructor
```

You could then construct your conjunct as `a & b(c) & d(e(f)) & g` and deal with it appropriately from there, knowing exactly what you mean by `&/2` - conjunction.

See the manual page for [`op/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=op/3) in SWI-PROLOG for more details - if you're not using SWI, I presume there should be a similar predicate in whatever PROLOG implementation your'e using -- if it's worth it's salt :-)

**EDIT:** To convert a tuple term constructed using `,/2` to a list, you could use  something like the following:

```
conjunct_to_list((A,B), L) :-
  !,
  conjunct_to_list(A, L0),
  conjunct_to_list(B, L1),
  append(L0, L1, L).
conjunct_to_list(A, [A]).
```

Comment: Your post answers why does such construction work (,/2 operator) but still I don't know whether it is the proper way to deal with such input. The problem is that I can't just deal with a list of terms because I get the tuple on input. Maybe there is a way to convert a tuple to list? Still I could do something like that:

convert((X, Xs), [X|R]) :- convert(Xs, R).
convert(X, [X]).

Comment: I've added `conjunct_to_list/2` which should help convert a term constructed with `,/2` to a list (`./2`).

Comment: You could have written the first one like this `conjunct_to_list((A, B), [A|T]) :- !, conjunct_to_list((B), T).`. But isn't there a way to do it without `!`?

Comment: @ohcibi You're mistaken. Consider what happens if `A = (a,b)` and `B = (c,d)` in the term `(A,B)`. Your example (if a base case was properly included) would likely produce the list `[(a,b),c,d]`. Note the two calls to expand both `A` _and_ `B` in my definition to cope with such nested terms. In fact, it will collapse _any_ `,/2` nested term to a list correctly.

Comment: @sharky I tried your solution and it actually does match [(a, b, c)], if you remove the cut. I'm not sure right now about [(a,b),c,d] but [a,b,(c,d)]. will be matched as well. Your solution has the exact same problem as mine, and the problem is in the second clause because there A can unify to (c,d). I solved it in the meantime by adding atomic(A) to it as (c,d) is not atomic.

Comment: @ohcibi what was the exact binding for `X` in a call to my description of `conjunct_to_list(X,L)` which bound `L` to `[(a,b),c,d]` or `[a,b,(c,d)]`?

Comment: @sharky again: remove your cut. Try out your example: It will produce exactly the list you have spoken of (A = (a,b), B = (c,d) makes [(a,b), c,d] among others). `atomic(A)` in the base case solves it (`conjunct_to_list(A, [A]):-atomic(A).`)

Comment: @ohcibi So you want a pure version, then? Your solution fails to handle anything other than conjuncts of atoms. For example, it would fail to process the conjunct `(a,f(b))`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... `a, b(c), d(e(f)), g` means `a` and (`b(c)` and (`d(e(f))` and `g`)), as well list `[1,2,3]` is just a `[1 | [2 | [3 | []]]]`. I.e. if you turn that conjuction to a list you'll get the same `test2([X|Xs]):-...`, but difference is that conjunction carries information about how that two goals is combined (there may be disjunction `(X; Xs)` as well). And you can construct other hierarchy of conjunctions by `(a, b(c)), (d(e(f)), g)`

You work with simple recursive types. In other languages lists is also recursive types but they often is pretending to be arrays (big-big tuples with nice indexing).

Probably you should use:

```
test2((X, Y)):- test2(X), nl, test2(Y).
test2((X; Y)). % TODO: handle disjunction
test2(X) :- write(X), nl.
```