# Turn a tuple into a list

Tags: list, prolog, tuples

I've searched and strangely didn't find much on this . How can I turn a tuple of unknown length into a list in prolog?

For example:

```
List=[1,2,3,4], Tuple=(1,2,3,4).
```

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2893766/1812457)

Answer (score 2):

When you are stuck with term conversion, it is often a good idea to get an understanding of what a term *actually* denotes.

You can use **`write_canonical/1`** to get the canonical form of a term.

In your case:

```
?- Tuple = (1,2,3,4), write_canonical(Tuple).
','(1,','(2,','(3,4)))
Tuple =  (1, 2, 3, 4).
```

This makes it clear that we are actually talking about **compound terms** of the form `(A,B)`—written in prefix notation as `','(A,B)`—whose arguments are either *integers* or again such compound terms. Such terms are also called "*and lists*" in Prolog, and Prolog **goals** also have such a shape. Note in particular that these are not really "tuples", certainly not in a "first class citizen" sense, only compound terms much like any other compound terms.

Thus, we only need to reason about these **2 possible cases**:

- integer
- term of the form `(A,B)`.

Further, when describing lists, always consider using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) notation for convenience.

For example:

```
tuple_list(I)     --> { integer(I) }, [I].
tuple_list((A,B)) --> tuple_list(A), tuple_list(B).
```

Now we have:

```
?- Tuple = (1,2,3,4), phrase(tuple_list(Tuple), Ls).
Tuple =  (1, 2, 3, 4),
Ls = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

This solves your task of converting from such terms **to** lists.

However, the most general query yields no answers:

```
?- phrase(tuple_list(Tuple), Ls).
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

I leave generalizing `tuples_list//1` so that it works **in all directions** as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You have got two useful answers already. As mentioned, you generally don't use a "tuple" in the notation `(1, 2, 3, 4)`: this is not a flat data structure as in say Haskell, it is a nested data structure. The Prolog way would be to use a term with arity 4, for example, `quadruple(1, 2, 3, 4)`. The name of course doesn't matter, but usually, you use a descriptive name of some sort.

Then, to convert the arguments of a term to a list, you use the "univ" operator `=..` like this:

```
Term =.. [Name|Arguments]
```

so:

```
?- foo(1, 2, 3, 4) =.. [foo|Args].
Args = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

In the special case of tuples with two elements (pairs), the functor `-/2` is commonly used. The dash is also an infix operator, so you can write `1-a` instead of `-(1, a)`. Quite a few library predicates that work on pairs expect them as `-/2`, for example:

```
?- keysort([1-c, 2-a, -(0, b), 1-a], S).
S = [0-b, 1-c, 1-a, 2-a].
```

Answer (score 0):

tuples in Prolog are rarely used, but a quick conversion could be

```
list_tuple([A,B|L], (A,R)) :- list_tuple([B|L], R).
list_tuple([A,B], (A,B)). % I don't think unary tuples make sense...

?- list_tuple([1,2,3,4],T).
T =  (1, 2, 3, 4) ;
false.
```

this doesn't work very well on 'backward mode'

```
?- list_tuple(L,(1,2,3,4)).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
L = [1, 2,  (3, 4)] ....
```

you can try to place a cut to get it deterministic, I've provided clauses in order as required...

Comment: I believe you need to modify the code as follows:

        `list_tuple([A,B,C|L], (A, R)) :- R = (B, _), !, list_tuple([B,C|L], R).
        list_tuple([A,B], (A,B)).`

Answer (score 0):

Using SWI-Prolog, "tuples" and lists can be converted using the built-in library predicate `comma_list/2`.

```
comma_list(C, [1, 2, 3]).
% C = (1, 2, 3).

comma_list((1, 2, 3), L).
% L = [1, 2, 3].

comma_list((a, foo(bar), C), [a, B, c]).
% C = c,
% B = foo(bar).
```

See the [documentation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prolog_code%3Acomma_list/2) for more usage examples.

It can be a bit tricky to search for because the documentation doesn't necessarily refer to terms like `(1, 2, 3)` as a "tuple", but it describes them as a "nested term over the `,/2` functor". Also provided is `semicolon_list/2` which will perform the same operations with the `;/2` functor instead.